# When does a character start to fall?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement

When does a character start to fall? Can a character use a power or ability mid-air before falling?

Example:

An Eladrin Fey Pact Warlock is standing on the edge of a chasm and kills a cursed enemy. Misty Step allows the Warlock to teleport 3 squares, and he does so, directly over the chasm (mid air). The Eladrin then activates Fey Step to teleport the remaining spaces to the other side of the chasm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Falls of <100 squares happen immediately. So unless the Warlock has a free action teleport(fey step is a move) he will fall. If the fall is over 500 ft he will get another turn before he falls another 500 ft (unless he stops the fall) and gets his full compliment of actions.

Teleportation that would subject a creature to a fall allows a save which negates the teleport.

In the case you are talking about, the warlock would fall into the chasm.

Answer (score 0):

I'd allow this one.  You can begin a jump at the end of your move action, and complete it with your standard action converted to a second move action*.  If you immediately fell 100 squares upon ending a move action, this would be impossible.  The fact that you *can* do this seems to indicate that falling begins after you run out of available movement.

- Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong on this.  I'm away from my books at the moment, and it's possible I'm mixing editions.

Comment: Actually, no, I double-checked.  Jumping uses movement, and if you *run out* of movement you fall, but you can end your *first* move in midair if you double move.  (PHB p.284)

Comment: Ok. You might want to incorporate that directly into the answer. Also, can you speak to the practical example of Misty Step + Fey Step (that is, does that work the same, or is it different)?